# Take screenshot of device screen like home screen,menu screen in android

Tags: android

I have used this code to take screenshot of my layout:

```
public static Bitmap screenshot(View v){

    Bitmap b=Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(),v.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c=new Canvas(b);
    v.draw(c);
    return b;
}
```

But it takes screenshot of views only.So my question how can I take screenshot of device screen e.g. home screen,menu screen,etc.I had searched about it but all is about taking screenshot of a view.how can I take screenshot of outside my app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programmatically take a screenshot in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programmatically-take-a-screenshot-in-android)

Comment: Use [the media projection APIs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjectionManager.html) on Android 5.0+.

Comment: This is not possible to do this using regular API

Comment: @Bryan hi I had gone through these questions these codes can take screenshot within the app only not device screen

Comment: @CommonsWare hi This is actually a better way but my minimum api is 17 and it requires 23

Comment: The media projection APIs are available starting with API Level 21. There is no means of doing this prior to API Level 21, outside of rooted devices.

Comment: ok is it possible to use media projection api in app having minimum api17

Comment: No, the media projection APIs are only available starting with API Level 21.

Comment: so are there any other solution